# How to use chmod inside Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have some users whose Directories are in /home/Army1. I have to change some permissions of those directories so i used

```
chmod o-rx /home/Army1
```

But when i build the Docker image, it says

```
chmod : cannot access : /home/Army1 : No such file or Directory
```

What can I do to resolve this problem.

PS. I haven't copied this directory in my Docker image.

Comment: If you haven't copied it, why should it be inside the container? The error is clearly stating what is the problem.

Comment: Use COPY command to copy that directory from local to docker image.

Comment: (Docker containers don't typically have multiple users and most images don't reference paths in `/home` at all.)